# How do I put /home in a different partition?

Tags: partitioning, directory, home-directory

Yeah, so I have 2 hard drives, on with 2 partitions(backups and windows), and I have another that also has 2 partitions with only one used. I have Ubuntu on hard drive 2:partition one, but I have come to a point when the /home folder can't hold any more files, but the partition is only about 15% filled up. So I did some researching and figured out that you can put it on a separate partition, but most of the guides were vague on what I needed to do.
Could someone give me step-by-step instructions on what I need to do, or even tell me a, easier or different way to fix this /home folder capacity problem?

Comment: Can you post the output of `sudo fdisk -l` (that's L, not 1). If the Ubuntu partition is only 15% full, Home should not be limited to 15% of its capacity.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this answer: [Change the default Downloads directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60161/change-the-default-downloads-directory/60179#60179)

Posted here for your convenience:

> **Ubuntu Tweak** can be useful for you this time, but includes the install of the [**Ubuntu Tweak**](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) software, whose intuitive GUI
>   will guide you on this and some other useful processes.
>
> When installed, simply choose Ubuntu Tweak from within the System
>   Tools sub-menu in the main menu. After which you can go to the
>   "Personal" section in the sidebar and look inside "Default folders",
>   where you can choose which will be your default folder for Downloads,
>   Documents, Desktop, etc.
>
> [image]
>
> I hope this help you.
>
> Good luck!

Unfortunately I haven't tested what you want to do but I have read that if you put the default home folder and other default folders in a different partitions, you will be in the need to auto-mount that partition in order not to experience a major issue at the boot.

Once I tried to do it with 2 different hard disk drives, which resulted in errors at the boot, solved by mounting the hard disk drive partition and closing the session and logging in again.

I hope you find a better solution but this may give you a clue on where to begin. Please inform how did you manage this issue.

Good luck!

Comment: That's not for your home directory, but for default directories in your home directory. There is a major difference.

Comment: This seems to be a problem of where the information is placed. Which can also be solved by sending the "default directories" to a different place, in whose case will lessen the overload for the "home directory". Anyway. Thank you for your observation.

Answer (score 1):

You normally use 2 partitions at least - better 3: One for the system, one for swap, and the third for home, on a single-user desktop system.

If you have plenty of RAM, you don't need swap, except for hibernation, which is a nice thing to have. You normally choose 1.5x your physical RAM-size for SWAP, if you don't have reason to do more or less.

So if you didn't use your second partition so far, I would use the opportunity to create a swap space, by splitting the free partition.

A separate partition for home is useful if an major upgrade fails. You can install a new system without touching your home, keeping all data, all settings, all emails and so on in place.

But you have to investigate, why you can only use 15% of the current partition.

For creating the new partition, I would suggest

```
sudo gparted
```

to repartition the free partition.

Later you format the one partition, which shall be the new /home with

```
mkfs.ext4
```

for an ext4-filesystem. You copy your home-folder content over, preserving attributes and permissions - the easiest way is to use the midnight commander - to preserve date/time as well, so that your files don't get the time/date of copying.

Then you mount testwise the new partition as /home. This will hide your old /home which makes it a bit tricky to delete it later, but you don't want to delete it, before it works.

For deleting the old content, you unmount /home, then you rename /home to /home-old, and create an empty /home folder for remounting the new partition. Then you can safely delete /home-old.