# How to rename the Desktop folder without breaking my system?

Tags: 11.10, unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it safe to rename special user folders?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22592/is-it-safe-to-rename-special-user-folders)

I'm currently using Ubuntu 11.10 in German. I noticed, that the Desktop folder's name is "Arbeitsfläche". Unfortunately I am used to "cd Desktop" instead of "cd Arbeitsfläche". Is it possible to rename my Arbeitsfläche to Desktop without breaking my system?

Comment: @Jakob reading the question I would say it is a duplicate. But the accepted answer seems off-topic to me. And the other answers don't seem to really give an "answer" to the question here.