# Rename default user directories

Tags: 12.04, directory, xdg

Is it possible to rename default directories like `~/Documents`, `~/Music`, `~/Videos`?

Especially I want to rename `Videos` to `Movies`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18103/how-can-i-change-the-default-location-of-content-directories-eg-pictures-templ?rq=1)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it safe to rename special user folders?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22592/is-it-safe-to-rename-special-user-folders)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, the default home folders are defined in `.config/user-dirs.dirs`, which is a hidden configuration file, and you can open it with `gedit .config/user-dirs.dirs`. It looks like this, which is, hopefully, self-explanitory:

```
# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
```

Logout/login for the changed to take effect.

Comment: And how can I rename these folders? I can change path here only.

Comment: Just type a different name, for example `"$HOME/Movies"` instead of `"$HOME/Videos"`.

Comment: I want to add that it took a restart for me to make the changes take effect. Wasn't obvious for me.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS and Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS, but BlueMan does not respect name change of *Downloads* directory - it is [bug 1778423](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/blueman/+bug/1778423).

Answer (score 5):

As I remember, Nautilus updates user directories if you simply rename them via the file manager. So I think right-clicking on the directory and choosing "Rename" from the menu should do the trick - just rename `Videos` to `Movies` in the file manager, it will remember the change.

Comment: That's right, I just did it this way - much more user-friendly.

Comment: Did not work for me on Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: @CharlyDelta in ubuntu you have to manually change the path. when you rename this "label" to Movies, the path isn't automatically updated, this is still pointing to the old "/home/username/Videos"