# How to share Home partition between several Linux distros without sharing configuartion and user preferences?

Tags: partitioning, home-directory, sharing

I use both Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and Deepin 15.9, sharing the same home partition, in order to be able to access my documents from both OSes.
Unfortunately, they have both access to the same configuration and user preferences, at least for some applications like Firefox, which runs perfectly on Ubuntu bur crashes on Deepin because of incompatible versions. 
When I run it again afterwards on Ubuntu it displays Restore Last Session (the one which crashed on Deepin).
What can I do to change this in simple instructions suitable for an average user.
Thanks.

Comment: Best not to share /home. You can share a data partition which can have all your data folders, but then not your hidden configuration settings. These suggestions apply whether on same driver or separate drives. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Comment: You could also use the procedures in [https://askubuntu.com/a/243567/283721](https://askubuntu.com/a/243567/283721) - you would want separate /home directories, but have the various data directories accessed by both systems.

Comment: One option is is to `mount` the directories you want to share over (or shadowing) your desired path, which can be achieved with only changes in `/etc/fstab`.  For example if you want to share `/home/user/Vidoes/` you include a mount for that, along with every other directory you want shared. They'll shadow the real 'Videos' in that directory so you'll achieve what you want. Unlike `/home/user/`  which covered all, you'll have to do it for all (wanted) directories; and they don't need to be local (eg.  I do it from a NFS [network file system] share rather than local disk.

Comment: Thank you all oldfred  Charles Green  guiverc, I finally did it and I now have separate Data and home partitions.